# Exception in finally block

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

If exception is raised in finally block of code, is the rest of finally block executed, or not?

```
try
  statementList1
finally
  command;
  command_that_raises;
  critical_command;
end
```

Will `critical_command` be executed?

[Manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Exceptions_(Delphi)#Try...finally_Statements) talks only about exceptions, not execution of code:

> If an exception is raised but not handled in the finally clause, that exception is propagated out of the try...finally statement, and any exception already raised in the try clause is lost. The finally clause should therefore handle all locally raised exceptions, so as not to disturb propagation of other exceptions.

Comment: The manual section you quote definitely pertains to your problem since you are asking *If an **exception** is raised in finally block of code...*. So I don't know why you think it doesn't apply. Exceptions occur as a result of executing code that cause such exception. According to the manual, if `command_that_raises` causes an exception, then unless you handle it within the `finally` block, you will lose the current exception and  `critical_command` will not be executed. Just like the manual says.

Comment: Well, I thought that, as the finally block is guaranteed to execute, all lines are enforced to be executed one by one. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: This is why you will typically see in finally blocks, only code that cannot raise.

Comment: The `finally` block is guaranteed to execute in the event of exception in the `try` block. It's not guaranteed to completely execute if the `finally` block itself experiences an exception. That's a different situation. You would need a `try-finally` block within the `finally` block for that.

Comment: Couldn't you figure this out in a quick console app with about 10 lines of code in it in about two minutes? Whatever happened to people actually trying to answer a question themselves with a little experimentation before running off to post a question that took much longer to write, format and post?

Comment: In retrospect, trying it out myself would be faster and simpler. But it baffled me that such a topic has not yet been discussed anywhere before.

Comment: Probably because it's so easy to test and the results are pretty easy to explain, nobody cared to discuss it before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following confirmation:

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  try
    ShowMessage('begin');
  finally
    ShowMessage('enter');
    raise Exception.Create('raise');
    ShowMessage('end');
  end;

end;
```

And now for this case:

```
procedure RaiseAndContinue;
begin
  try
    raise Exception.Create('raise');
  except

  end;
end;

procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  try
    ShowMessage('begin');
  finally
    ShowMessage('enter');
    RaiseAndContinue;
    ShowMessage('end');
  end;

end;
```

The short answer is: unless you handle that exception then **No** the code will not be executed.